# What can cause a Cloud Run instance to not be reused despite continuous load?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

**Context:**

My Spring-Boot app runs as expected on Cloud Run when I deploy it with max-instances set to 1: It receives a constant stream of pubsub messages via push, and makes anywhere from 0 to 5 writes to an associated CloudSQL instance, depending on the message payload. Typically it handles between 20 and 40 messages per second. Latency/response-time varies between 50ms and 60sec, probably due to some resource contention.

In order to increase throughput/ decrease resource contention, I'm looking to experiment with the connection pool size per app-instance, as well as the concurrency and max-instances parameters for my cloud run app.

I understand that due to Spring-Boot, my app has a relatively high cold-start time of about 30-40 seconds. This is acceptable for how this service is used.

**Problem:**

I'm experiencing problems when deploying a spring-boot app to cloud run with max-instances set to a value greater than 1:

- **Instances start, handle a single request successfully, and then produce no more logs.**
- This happens a few times per minute, leading me to believe that instances get started (cold-start), handle a single request, die, and then get started again. They are not being reused as described in the docs, and as is happening when I set max-instances to 1. [Official docs on concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency)
- Instead, I expect 3 container instances to be started, which then each requests according to max-concurrency setting.

**Billable container time at max-instances=3:**
[image: Billable container time graph]

- As shown in the graph, the number of instances is fluctuating wildly, once the new revision with max-instances=3 is deployed.
- The graphs for CPU- and memory-usage also look like this.
- There are no error logs. As before at max-instaces=1, there are warnings indicating that there are not enough instances available to handle requests (HTTP 429).
- Connection Limit of CloudSQL instance has not been exceeded
- Requests are handled at less than 10/s

Finally, this is the command used to deploy:

```
 gcloud beta run deploy my-service --project=[...] --image=[...] --add-cloudsql-instances=[...] --region=[...] --platform=managed --memory=1Gi --max-instances=3 --concurrency=3 --no-allow-unauthenticated
```

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: You are making very big incorrect assumptions about Cloud Run. Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system with code as a container. Everything is a single request with a single response. Design your system that way. Also, when you talk about latency, show how you measure it. Just opening a TCP/IP connection over a long distance can take 100 ms. Do not use threading as that will not improve anything. Make an HTTP request to Cloud Run, receive an HTTP response. Nothing else. Do not rely on state, do not assume the same instance will run again on the next request. Do not attempt to multitask.

Comment: If those requirements do not meet your goals, then use a different compute service.

Comment: Hi John, according to the cloud run docs, container instances are reused to serve incoming requests, and can handle multiple requests concurrently. The latency numbers I provided are the ones measured by the cloud run dashboard itself. My application is stateless. Connectiosn are made from google pubsub to the cloud run instance, which are in the same network, so no distances here. I am not using threading, I had a typo in the question where I was talking about a "threadpool" when I really meant connectionpool.

Comment: A connection pool will not help you either. No background threads, connections, etc. The container lifetime exists only between request and response.

Comment: Connection pooling is a recommended practice from the cloud run docs. While using multiple threads is inefficient, when there's only a single CPU core available, how exactly does this prevent the container instance from being reused for multiple requests? It works for max-instances 1 after all - identical code and configuration.

Comment: If you read the docs, you will find that the container CPU can be idled to zero between requests. This will cause TCP/IP connections to fail. The instance may be reused, but that does not mean that "state" can be reused. That is a recipe for problems that are difficult to debug.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What kind of state do you think I am reusing? The other things you said I understand and I am aware of.

Comment: Hi, I have seen a lot of interaction here for your question with no clear root cause of what may be affecting the scaling of your Cloud Run service. 
Have you tried to reach out to Google support? I think they have more tools that can help you shed some light

Answer (score 1):

Some month ago, in private Alpha, I performed tests and I observed the same behavior. After discussion with Google team, I understood that instances are over provisioned "in case of": an instances crashes, an instances is preempted, the traffic suddenly increase,...

The trade-off of this is that you will have more cold start that your max instances values. ***Worse***, you will be charged for this over provisioned cold start -> **this is not an issue because Cloud Run has a huge free tier that covers this kind of glitches.**

Going deeper in the logs (you can do it by creating a sink of Cloud Run logs into BigQuery and then by requesting them), even if there is more instances up than your max instances, only your max instances are active in the same time. *I'm not sure to be clear. With your parameters, that means, if you have 5 instances up in the same time, only 3 serve the traffic at the same point of time*

This part is not documented because it evolves constantly for find the best balance between over-provisioning and lack of ressources (and 429 errors).

@Steren @AhmetB can you confirm or correct me?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. At the time of writing the question, the service was consuming over 100k pubsub messages at a rate of less than 10/s. I don't understand how overprovisioning fits into the picture here, as it seems to me the service is severely underprovisioned. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I can't. I observed the same things, and I shared with you the details provided by Googler on this strange behavior. The scalability algorithm takes into account several factors, the query rate, the processing time, the CPU usage,... Maybe some Google internal metrics, and some heuristics on usage. It's Google secret sauce!

Answer (score 0):

When Cloud Run receives and processes requests rapidly, it predicts how many instances it needs, and will try to scale to the amount. If a sudden burst of requests occur, Cloud Run will instantiate a larger number of instances as a response. This is done in order to adapt to a possible higher number of network requests beyond what it is currently serving, with attempts to take into consideration the length of time it will take for the existing instance to complete loading the request. Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling), it is possible that the amount of container instances can go above the max instance value when it spikes.

You mentioned with max-instances set to 1 it was running fine, but later you mentioned  it was in fact producing 429s with it set to 1 as well. Seeing behavior of 429s as well as the instances spiking could indicate that the amount of traffic is not being handled fluidly.

It is also worth noting, because of the cold start time you mention, when instances are serving the first request(s), by design, the number of concurrent requests is actually hard set to 1. Once things are fully ready,only then the concurrency setting you have chosen is applied.

Was there some specific reason you chose 3 and 3 for Max Instance settings and concurrency? Also how was the concurrency set when you had max instance set to 1? Perhaps you could try tinkering up further the [concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency) (max 80) and /or [Max instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances) (high limit up to 1000) and see if that removes the 429s.

Comment: 429s are also present when I'm running on one instance. Pubsub will increase the rate it's pushing messages at, until a non 2xx response occurs, so this is expected behaviour, regardless of instance count.

Comment: I understand that the number of instances can fluctuate. What I don't understand is that container instances are not being reused for more than a single request, while there is sufficient load. If I understand correctly, they should be reused - and regardless of concurrency setting.

Comment: As for the settings, since the instance runs on a single core, to avoid overhead introduced by thread switching, I want to keep concurrency low (1-3), and scale via number of instances. Right now concurrency is at 40, which is why the latency fluctuates so greatly under load: 50ms to 60s - probably depending on how long the thread has to wait on a sql connection being available. 3 instances x 3 concurrency = 9 sql connections, which is what I want to work with at this stage.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I suppose the documentation you are referring about the reuse is https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#using_global_variables ? . If it is I guess it is a bit ambiguous in that it says "Whether any individual request receives the benefit of this reuse cannot be known ahead of time."  Are you able to share some of what you see in the Stackdriver logging at the time?

Comment: I am referring to the docs at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency 

Per container instance I see the logs pertaining to spring boot startup, and then a single log entry about a single 200 response. This combination of log happens several times per minute, each time with a new container instance id.

Comment: "each time with a new container instance id" - just to clarify this. Are you saying that over (let's say) 1000 requests with --max instances set to 3, in the Stackdriver logs, you are actually seeing 1000 different InstanceIDs? (ie 1 for each request?) I ran a load balance test (not the same as what you are doing admittedly)  against the sample SpringBoot app just to see how it handled the traffic and it did seem to recycle the instance id. Ie only found unique 3 InstanceIDs across the 1000 requests. I was looking at Labels - InstanceId.

Comment: I did not yet sink the logs into a DB to figure out exact numbers, so take these observations with a grain of salt:
At a given time, there seems to be a "main instance" that remains "up" for 2-3 minutes at a time, which handles requests continuously during that time. On the other hand there are dozens of instances that start up (i see the spring init logs) and then log a single 200 response. Your comment gives me hope, that I'ts a mistake on my part and there is a change I can make to fix it :)

Comment: I'm working on a different part of the system now, but will come back to this issue at a later stage to provide more data.